# Unable to locate element even if it's visible with Selenium 4

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium with geckodriver to click some element. After page structure changed with an update, this element cannot be clicked. To open the driver I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = r'D:\Archivos de programas\firefox.exe'
profile_path = r'C:/Users/Isaac/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/lpq195ye.eloimusqueira'

options.profile = profile_path

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('http://www.faceit.com/en/tournaments')
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.sc-cjaHrE:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1)')
element.click()
```

But I'm getting the return that it's unable to locate the element. I'm debugging, also putting some waits so I'm sure if it's visible for the driver but it can't be clicked. This is weird, as for example, the other elements in the left (see picture(1)) are totally clickable without any problem. How I fix this? Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="sc-jaVtyD bVVXki">
  <div class="sc-cjaHrE bmcaef sc-ieXEqj sc-gZIk cKFQjo iIPvdc">
    <a href="/en/championship/b921e728-c3d8-495c-8264-c858ce3eacce/Double%20Tap" class="sc-eBrWha ebVZdP">
      <div class="sc-iYhvPj bHbeQq">
        <div class="sc-iYhvPj bHbeQq">
          <div class="sc-irRVhh iibNNB">
            <span class="sc-bHMEaB gpNZjM">In 52 minutes, 20:00 GMT+1</span>
            <span class="sc-hZjMBx jzVAEl">Double Tap</span>
            <div class="sc-dprTRw fCGkDI">
              <div class="sc-cbAqmX inLmbd">
                <span class="sc-hZjMBx sc-rrnBE sc-iovYwi ijfQzb dtaMpL jTgylJ">Organized by</span>
                <span href="/en/organizers/faceit/FACEIT" class="sc-hZjMBx sc-rrnBE sc-liicZZ ijfQzb dtaMpL fIObt">FACEIT</span>
              </div>
              <span class="sc-hZjMBx sc-rrnBE ijfQzb dtaMpL">1v1 · Single Elimination</span>
            </div>
            <div class="sc-elpIZQ hDZBdc middleSlotMobile">
              <div class="sc-cXyfvr bhvLTb">
                <div class="sc-jktNEC itvLyn">
                  <div class="sc-fJGgZf hAYOIE">
                    <svg class="sc-bSGnmh bKeeJz sc-gMjomW gvnnZZ" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <title>Skill level 9</title>
                      <use xlink:href="#f_icon_e6c73405"></use>
                    </svg>
                    <span>-</span>
                    <svg class="sc-bSGnmh bKeeJz sc-gMjomW gvnnZZ" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <title>Skill level 10</title>
                      <use xlink:href="#f_icon_aff4d555"></use>
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sc-jCzwfO jXhEtU">
                  <i class="sc-ehvNnt huJUra sc-izWoRX sc-jnPKpB gTGHmS dVbwrX">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 14 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" color="primary" height="16" width="16" class="sc-laZRCg kLYQOq">
                      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M.7.667C0 1.333 0 2 0 2.667V16h4.2v-5.333H14v-4H4.2v-2C4.2 4.252 4.652 4 5.52 4H14V0H4.9C3.5 0 1.4 0 .7.667z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                    </svg>
                  </i>
                  <span class="sc-hZjMBx sc-rrnBE jigzmw dtaMpL">4,000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="sc-bZlFrE iWGUwT">
                  <i class="sc-ehvNnt huJUra sc-WIydN fDmdzC">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" color="whiteMediumEmphasis" height="20" width="20" class="sc-laZRCg fbAvqI">
                      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M19 20H22V18C22 15.7909 20.2091 14 18 14H17C17 14 19 15.5 19 18V20Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20 9C20 10.3445 19.1652 11.5761 18 12V6H20V9Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15 18L9 18C9 16.8954 9.89543 16 11 16H13C14.1046 16 15 16.8954 15 18ZM7 20V18C7 15.7909 8.79086 14 11 14H13C15.2091 14 17 15.7909 17 18V20H7Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M14 6H10V9C10 9.55228 10.4477 10 11 10H13C13.5523 10 14 9.55228 14 9V6ZM8 4V9C8 10.6569 9.34315 12 11 12H13C14.6569 12 16 10.6569 16 9V4H8Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M5 20H2V18C2 15.7909 3.79086 14 6 14H7C7 14 5 15.5 5 18V20Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M4 9C4 10.3445 4.83481 11.5761 6 12V6H4V9Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                    </svg>
                  </i>
                  <span class="sc-hZjMBx sc-rrnBE jigzmw dtaMpL">3/16</span>
                </div>
              </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Structure of the element I'm trying to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovill.png)

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Comment: Hi @jeffC thanks for the help, I'm kinda new with html. I posted the code, but its not visible. I paste the element I wanted to paste, but I dont know if I should poste all the HTML code of the page. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You needed to format the HTML as code. I fixed it. Having said that... it's very likely that it's not going to be enough to help with your problem. You'll need to post more of the surrounding HTML.

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob. Ok I updated with elements above and under the item I want to select. Can I ask if an element is clickable by XPATH it will be selected also by CSS selector?

Comment: XPath and CSS selectors are just two ways to select the same element. Most elements can be selected by both. The exceptions are that XPath can select elements by contained text and do some more complicated DOM traversals where CSS selectors cannot. That said, I use CSS selectors everywhere possible because they are better supported by the browser, faster, and the syntax is simpler.

Comment: Given the HTML you've posted, there aren't enough elements to see what the issue with the locator is. All you've provided is the first `div.sc-cjaHrE`. From that one, the second half of the locator is fine, e.g. `div.sc-cjaHrE:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)`. Check and see if `div.sc-cjaHrE:nth-child(4)` exists on the page. If you aren't familiar, you can test locators (at least using Chrome) using the dev console. Press F12, then ESC, and then type `$$("...")` for CSS selectors and `$x("...")` for XPaths. In this case, `$$("div.sc-cjaHrE:nth-child(4)")`. Is an element found?